# Disable radio buttons default in Woocommerce

Tags: radio-button, woocommerce

Sorry for my English. Can I disable the default choice radio buttons for shipping costs and payments in Woocommerce? I would like to have radio buttons blank. In short, the radio buttons are activated only when the user clicks. If a user does not fill in, example, the radio button of the shipment will go a window "Attention, choose the method of delivery." I hope I was clear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [this](https://www.xadapter.com/woocommerce-clear-default-shipping-and-payment-options-on-cartcheckout-page/) code snippet

```
// To test this code, open a private/incognito window,
   add an item to the cart and then go to cart page.
// Once an option is choosen, it will be the default option 
   from that moment onwards.

// Code to clear default shipping option.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', '__return_false');
```

Comment: I just removed the last ");"... it works.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce automatically chooses the cheapest shipping method available if you do not have a default setup.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCm8a.png

See the Automatic option at the bottom of the Shipping Methods section? That ensures that it would always choose a radio button.

I'm not saying this is impossible, but it would involve changing the underlying code.

May I know the reason behind not having a default option set? It sounds inefficient in my opinion. If the user does not like the default option, they can easily change it. At least this way, you no longer have to worry about putting in a "Please Choose A Shipping Method" validation.

The default shipping saves clicks for most of your clients especially if you pick the right option as default. The least clicks the better. ;)

Cheers!

As an update based on our discussion below, here's an option to hide the default shipping option...

Say "Free Shipping" is the default option. All you have to do is to add this code to your css...

```
#shipping_method_0_free_shipping{
display:none !important;
}
```

Then, the WooCommerce>Settings>Shipping Methods dashboard, remove the "Free Shipping" label and change it to a "." (if you make it blank, this will not work) so that no label will appear after the shipping button is handled.

However, this just makes sure that the default shipping method does not appear to the user.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX8tL.png

The system will still consider it existing. You still need to prevent the checkout from proceeding if "Free Shipping" was the chosen shipping method.

Comment: is a request made by my client. 
He made this request because if the user clicks "forward, forward" without reading can make a wrong order. 
I know it is absurd, but my client said he had the "radio buttons" empty and if in case the customer forgets the option to choose a screen "attention ....." 
I do not know if I was clear, my english is bad!

Comment: I understand. :) I don't see an appropriate WooCommerce hook/filter for this. This usually means WooCommerce wants the feature present.    Check the explanation from one of the WooCommerce devs... https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/4698   They require a default shipping option as a shipping method is always required. Can your client's desire be a result of an issue with the way the Shipping Methods are Setup? If he is afraid that the wrong shipping option is chosen for a particular product, he can limit the shipping method for a certain type of product.

Comment: Meanwhile, thanks for the explanations always friendly and detailed. 
The site is an ecommerce electric bikes and nothing else. 
the fact is that the owner of the site is "affectionate" to the type "old" sites where the radio buttons are all empty and the customer must choose from time to time. 
I understand and agree with the reasons I said. 
I just have to find the right way to explain the inability of owner. Tips? 
Thank you very much :)

Comment: I don't want to assume things about your client... Have you gone over the way he sets up the products/payment/shipping? What exactly is his worry about "making the wrong order?" :) From what I can see with my WooCommerce setups, you can change the shipping and payment method up to the final point before you press the final Order button.

Comment: In fact ... that's what I tell myself. The customer can always change your choice of shipments (always before clicking order). 
I am a bit in trouble! 
Let's say the user who logs on to e-commerce is not always knows how to use the pc and "derivatives"

Comment: Best I can recommend is that to explain to him that Editing WooCommerce code that can't be accessed through WooCommerce Filters and Hooks is not recommended. Anything you change will disappear on the next update. It may also compromise other aspects of the system.

Comment: btw, I edited my answer with a 50% work around. It gives you half of your needs..(erase the default option). You still need to find a way for checkout to proceed only if the shipping option is not the default option. :)